# Existence of covering space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I would like to know that if $X$ is a connected topological space, there is always a covering space of it, i.e., a continuous map $p:X'\to X$ with the known property.

Comment: Just a covering space? Sure, take $X' = X$ and $p$ the identity.

Comment: The existence of a cover is rather obvious, the difficulties arise when you want a universal cover.